# numericUpDown control to increment according to column in DataTable

Tags: c#, numericupdown

On Form Load I tried this:

```
numericUpDown1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Value", dt, "ID", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation));
```

This didn't worked for me, the data field incremented by one.

but the column ID has different values that doesn't increment by one.
How can I use the up or down button of the object and the data field will be changed according to the next value of id column?
Thanks.

Comment: So when you press up or down the Id column should modify according with your `numericUpDown` control?

Comment: Nope, the numericUpDown control modify according to the ID column.

Comment: Have you tried to simply modify the value of your control? (`numericUpDown1.value` =?)